# R: write s3 object metadata

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I'm using R package [aws.s3](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3) with an S3 bucket on Amazon Web Services.  Is there a way to write the metadata for bucket objects from R?

Below code is for reading meta data from S3.

```
library(aws.s3)
head_object("my_object", bucket = "my_bucket")

[1] TRUE
attr(,"x-amz-id-2")
[1] "abc"
attr(,"x-amz-request-id")
[1] "abc"
attr(,"date")
[1] "Sat, 08 Dec 2018 00:01:34 GMT"
attr(,"last-modified")
[1] "Fri, 07 Dec 2018 20:45:47 GMT"
attr(,"etag")
[1] "\"abc\""
attr(,"x-amz-meta-source-info")
[1] "how can I write this from R?"  <---- created meta data in AWS console
attr(,"accept-ranges")
[1] "bytes"
attr(,"content-type")
[1] "application/zip"
attr(,"content-length")
[1] "100"
attr(,"server")
[1] "AmazonS3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `put_object()` and `save_object()` have an argument called `headers`. That's where the metadata for your `s3_object` goes. [AWS suggests that custom metadata tags need to be prefixed by `x-amz-meta-`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html#add-object-metadata-user-defined) and need to have a matching value.

Creating a list of keys and values then matching them up is probably the easiest way to do this:

```
keys <- list("key1", "key2")
values <- list("unlock", "does-not-unlock")

keys <- lapply(function(x) paste0("x-amz-meta-", x))

metadata <- setNames(values, keys)

put_object(file, object, bucket, headers = metadata)
```